# JPA MantyToOne update implementation

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, toplink

i want to ask how implement such thing like updating entity with @ManyToOne relationship. I have two tables Documents and DocType type like that

 Doucments 
`@JoinColumn(name = "doctype", referencedColumnName = "document_id")
     @ManyToOne
     private DocType doctype;`

 DocType 
`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "doctype")
     private Collection<Documents> DocCollection;`

When user need update doctype he type value in combobox wich contain all doctypes names in string .Then I find doctype entity, where doctype name like value selected in combobox and then i set that doctype entity to documents entity.
`public void saveDoc() { 
     entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
     currentEntitydoc.setDocType(getDocTypeEntity(ComboBox.getSelectedValue()));
     entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
     }`

Where getDocTypeEntity() like 
`public DocType getDocTypeEntity ( String userInput) { 
     query = manager.createQuery(
    "Select type from DocType type Where type.name=:arg1"
    );
    query.setParameter("arg1" , userInput);
    List<DocType> list  = query.getResultList();
    if (list.size() < 1  ) { 
    System.out.println ("can't find such DocType name); 
    } 
    return list.get(0);
    }`

Seem that it is a very often task , **how do u implement such things ? is there a better way do this in JPA ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entities have IDs, which uniquely identify them. And the EntityManager allows getting an entity given its type and its ID. So all you need is

```
DocType docType = em.find(DocType.class, docTypeId);
```

or even

```
DocType docType = em.getReference(DocType.class, docTypeId);
```

which doesn't even need to issue a select query (and returns an unitilized proxy).

You shouldn't use the name of the Doctype as the select options value, but its ID.